# Finding customer magento version

Tags: magento

I would like to know if you can take a client version of magento. For example i want to have an input field where the client will insert website url, after that website will show Magento Version of Customer is:

Is there any way to get customer Magento Version?

Thank you so much

Comment: Its displayed in admin footer.No other place on html.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but all i want is to have something like this http://magentoversion.com/

Comment: That link is not giving proper results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Magento version from `app/Mage.php` by calling the fuction `getVersionInfo()`

That returns an array as follows :

```
array(
    'major'     => '1',
    'minor'     => '6',
    'revision'  => '1',
    'patch'     => '0',
    'stability' => '',
    'number'    => '',
);
```

Version of the above returned is : 1.6.1.0

For more refer this : https://kb.magenting.com/content/5/86/en/verifying-magento-version.html

====

This thing you should do:

Create a front controller with a public function 
Write the bellow code in that method :

```
$mageobj = new Mage;
$version = $mageobj->getVersion();
return $version;
```

This will return the magento version

Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but how I can get magento version from other websites sonething like in this page http://magentoversion.com/

Comment: Give me some time, i will get back to you with the full discription

Comment: thank you so much, can you tell me how will look public function with an input field where url will be?

Comment: look here i found some things on github, can you tell me how can I use that? https://gist.github.com/jayelkaake/1541793

Comment: No that will not help, As I edited the answer, that will work if we have access for source, I'm researching about your problem only and trying to get solution for it. One of the solution I got is we have access the site like this www.somemagentosite.com/downloader (Every magento site has this page) It will redirect to magento downloader site, We have to access the html of this page and using JQuery we should access the footer content and get the version.

Comment: yes indeed, you're right, so you have any idea how we can make that function with an input field?

Comment: You have to use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ this method and get the html content of site.com/downloader and get the version